# How to get entity of channel by an invite link

Tags: python, telegram, telethon

I need to join to the channel by its invite link and after get its entity.
To join i use this code.

```
updates = await client(functions.messages.ImportChatInviteRequest('XXXXXXX'))
```

But if user already is participant i do not get updates with its entity, it just throws an error.

```
await client.get_entity('invite_link')
```

It does not work with invite links, with or without '+' at the beginning.

How can i get entity in both situations?

Answer (score 0):

i found, i think, the only way to get entity with subscribing to channel:

1. I understand that if user is member of private channel, you can get its entity by `entity = await self.client.get_entity('https://t.me/joinchat/' + invite_link)` (invite_link is 'XXXXXX' without '+')
2. If user is not a member, you need to join it by `await self.client(functions.messages.ImportChatInviteRequest(invite_link))`.
   it returns updates object:

```
updates = await self.client(functions.messages.ImportChatInviteRequest(invite_link))

entity = updates.chats[0]
```

this entities are equal
The code together is:

```
                    try:
                        entity = await self.client.get_entity(
                            'https://t.me/joinchat/' + invite_link)  # channel exists and user joined
                    except Exception as ex:
                        if 'you are not part of' in str(ex):  # Channel exists but user not joined
                            res1 = await self.client(functions.messages.ImportChatInviteRequest(invite_link))
                            entity = res1.chats[0]
                        else:
                            pass
```

Comment: You can accept your own answer if it solved your question.